# Is clEnqueueNDRangeKernel ever synchronous?

Tags: opencl

The following code does not use any callbacks or `clWaitForEvents` and yet it works perfectly. But I thought clEnqueueNDRangeKernel was non-blocking.

```
void CL::executeApp1()
{
    cl_int status = 0;
    const int d1Size = 1024000;
    int* myInt = new int[d1Size];

    cl_mem mem1 = clCreateBuffer(context, 0, sizeof(int)*d1Size, NULL, &status);
    status = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(queue, mem1, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int)*d1Size, myInt, 0, NULL, NULL);
    status = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &mem1);

    size_t global[] = {d1Size};
    cl_event execute;
    status = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, global, NULL, 0, NULL, &execute);
    //clWaitForEvents(1, &execute);
    status = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, mem1, CL_FALSE, 0, sizeof(int)*d1Size, myInt, 0, NULL, NULL);

    string s = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < d1Size; i++)
    {
        s += to_string(myInt[i]);
        s += " ";
    }

    result = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*s.length());
    strcpy(result, s.c_str());
}
```

Comment: Non blocking but sequential synced if you use a queue of type "in-order" and only one queue exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats true is non-blocking.

However you only have 1 queue, and it is probably not set as OUT_OF_ORDER_QUEUE. So, it will run everything in order.

First the write, then the kernel, and finally the read.
If you don't use two queues for IO and execution, the only call that needs to be blocking is the readBuffer().

Comment: so we cannot call multiple kernels in parallel on a device?